# Powershell remove-item with a timer?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a script where my users get to install programs in on their computers.
the logic is -> copy from network path the installation file to the local hard drive of the computer,
run the installation file with different creds
I want to then delete the file but this code isnt good

```
copy-item "$path1" -Destination C:\ProgramData\ #copy from network path to local
$progyname = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($path1) #holding the programname.exe
Start-Process powershell -Credential $creds -workingdirectory c:\programdata\  -ArgumentList "-Command &{Start-Process $progyname -Verb RunAs}"
Remove-Item -path c:\programdata\$progyname -Force
```

Problem is the script will delete the item too soon, i actually want to wait for the installation to be completed and then delete the file.

what could work here?

Comment: take a look at this >>> `Get-Help Start-Process -Parameter wait` <<<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the passthru parameter for start-process, save the returned ID to a variable and wait until the process is closed and youre good to delete

Comment: Thats sounds like a good idea. do you have any referance to such thing?

Comment: ```$process = start-process [your command] -passthru

Comment: wait-process -id $process.id      - gives me access is denied error, is this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
copy-item "$path1" -Destination C:\ProgramData\ #copy from network path to local
$progyname = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($path1) #holding the programname.exe
Start-Process powershell -Credential $creds -workingdirectory c:\programdata\  -ArgumentList "-Command &{Start-Process $progyname -Verb RunAs}"
$pro = $progynane.basename
If (!(Get-Process $pro -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)){Remove-Item -path c:\programdata\$progyname -Force}
```

Or if you like you can `-Wait` parameter at end of `Start-Process` as @Lee_Dailey pointed.

Comment: How would i know 'program_name' ? the program .exe file name is $progyname . is that what you mean?

Comment: ($progyname -replace ".exe","") is it.

Comment: Get-Process : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command aga
in.     -im not sure $progyname.basename hold anything